# Proving that if the Simson line of a triangle goes through the orthocenter, then the pole must be at a vertex.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I’ve already proven that if the Simson line goes through its pole then the pole is at a vertex. Similarly, I’ve proven that if it is perpendicular to one of its sides then the pole must again be at a vertex. How can I prove this for when it goes through the orthocenter? Thanks in advance

Comment: If the pole is not a vertex then Simpson line bisects $PH$, with $P$ being the pole and $H$ the orthocenter, so it can't contain $H$.